# LMER Factor vs numeric Interaction

Tags: categorical-data, lme4-nlme, contrasts

I am attempting to use lmer to model my data.

My data has 2 independent variables and a dependent variable.

The first is "Morph" and has values "Identical", "Near", "Far".
The second is "Response" which can be "Old" or "New".
The dependent variable is "Fix_Count".

So here is a sample dataframe and what I currently have for running the linear model.

```
 Subject <- c(rep(1, times = 6), rep(2, times = 6))
 q <- c("Identical", "Near", "Far")
 Morph <- c(rep(q, times = 4))
 t <- c(rep("old", times = 3),rep("new", times=3))
 Response <- c(rep(t, times = 2))
 Fix_Count <- sample(1:9, 12, replace = T)
 df.main <- data.frame(Subject,Morph, Response, Fix_Count, stringsAsFactors = T)

 res = lmer(Fix_Count ~ (Morph * Response) + (1|Subject), data=df.main)
 summary(res)
```

And the output looks like this:
[image: Stats Output]

The issue is I do not want it to do combination but an overall interaction of Morph:Response.

I can get it to do this by converting Morph to numeric instead of factor. However I'm not sure conceptually that makes sense as the values don't properly represent 1,2,3 but low-mid-high (ordered but qualitative).

So: 
1. Is it possible to run lmer to get interaction effects between 2 factor variables?
2. Or do you think numeric is a fine way to class "Identica", "Near", "Far"?
3. I have tried setting contrasts to see if that can help, but sometimes I get an error and other times it seems like nothing is changed. If contrasts would help, could you explain how I would implement this?

Thank you so much for any help you can offer. Please let me know if this Q is better off on stackoverflow if it turns out the answer is a coding issue not a stats issue.

Best,
Kirk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) it is possible and you have done it. You are simply looking at a table that doesn't show "overall" interaction. The effects in the table you posted are coefficients of the two interactions in the linear model. The overall interaction effect is in an ANOVA table, which is printed with anova()

```
> anova(res) # assumes lmerTest is loaded
Analysis of Variance Table of type III  with  Satterthwaite 
approximation for degrees of freedom
               Sum Sq Mean Sq NumDF DenDF F.value Pr(>F)
Morph          13.167  6.5833     2     5 1.18976 0.3779
Response        3.000  3.0000     1     5 0.54217 0.4946
Morph:Response  4.500  2.2500     2     5 0.40663 0.6861
```

2) and 3) the short answer is, neither recoding the variable to numeric or using contrasts will get what you want. The long answer is, this will all become more more clear as you progress in statistics and better understand what a linear model is, what contrasts are and what an anova table (or decomposition) is. It's not easy.